# How can I check which XSLT processor is being used in Solr?

Tags: xslt, solr

How can I verify which XSLT processor is being used in Solr? I want to change the XSLT version from 1.0 to 2.0.

I am using Solr 4.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
```

to identify the processor and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
```

to identify the version of XSLT it supports.

Comment: i have set xslt version 1.0 to 2.0 look like <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> but when i have check xslt version using <version><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/></version> its return <version>1.0</version> so what should i do to convert into xslt 2.0

Comment: @JatinPatel You need to change your processor. I am afraid I know nothing about Apache Solr, so I cannot tell you how (or if it's possible at all).